# Sqlite Optional Parameters?

Tags: sqlite, insert

I have a log table, using System.Data.Sqlite (C# on .NET 4.5) to write to a single table with 12 columns. Some of the columns might be written for a row, some might not. Is there a way to have a single parameterized Insert statement, only specifying n parameters, and let the rest automatically set to null?

I am thinking of the equivalent of a MS SQL Server stored procedure where multiple input parameters can be specified as null, and then a single insert statement within the sproc would insert nulls as needed.

Thanks.

Comment: SQLite doesn't have stored procedures.  The best you can do here is create a utility function to abstract that logic away from the rest of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Use `null` or `DBNull.Value`; see 
[NULL values and SQLiteParameters](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/37/96.aspx).